# Support for hydraulic engineering projects in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem, hydrology

How is a DTM used in hydraulic engineering projects when working with QGIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QGIS using GRASS to do modelling of Hydrology and DTMs

> GRASS GIS, commonly referred to as GRASS (Geographic Resources
> Analysis Support System), is a free Geographic Information System
> (GIS) software used for geospatial data management and analysis, image
> processing, graphics/maps production, spatial modeling, and
> visualization.

http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Hydrological_Sciences#Hydrological_models

Download
http://grass.osgeo.org/download/